# Getting Text From the ListView in customAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have a problem in getting the particular textview value and i am getting the value of the last one Here is My code of getview() of customAdapter
Basically what i want is to update the Quantity text on plus button click and vice-versa

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater=((Activity) activity).getLayoutInflater();
        final HashMap<?, ?> map=list.get(position);
        if(convertview==null)
        {
        convertview=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewdetails,parent,false);
        holder = new Viewholder();
        holder.title=(TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.lserving_size_grams);
        holder.servingsize=(TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.ltvprotiendesclabel);
        holder.Fiber=(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.lFiberview);
        holder.lserving_qty=(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.lvalueserving);
        holder.ckbox=(CheckBox)convertview.findViewById(R.id.lsave_item_box);
        holder.sminus=(ImageView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.limage_minus);
        holder.splus=(ImageView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.limage_plus);

        convertview.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
          {
             holder=(Viewholder)convertview.getTag();
          }

         //On Check Box Check Events


         holder.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
         holder.splus.setOnClickListener(null);
         holder.ckbox.setChecked(checkedItems[position]);
         holder.ckbox.setTag(R.id.lsave_item_box, position);
         //holder.splus.setOnClickListener(null);
         holder.lserving_qty.setText(checkedAddSub[position] ? qtysavesearch[position] :                                                  map.get(Constants.NF_SERVING_SIZE_QTY).toString());

         holder.splus.setTag(R.id.limage_plus,position);


         /*
          * Plus Btn click Listener
          */
         holder.splus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     final int position = (Integer) v.getTag(R.id.limage_plus);

                     // holder.lserving_qty.getText(checkedAddSub[position] ? qtysavesearch[position] : map.get(Constants.NF_SERVING_SIZE_QTY).toString());

                     //counter=Math.round(Float.valueOf(serving_size_qty[position]));
                     counter=Math.round(Float.valueOf(holder.lserving_qty.getText().toString()));
                    if(counter>=1)
                    {   
                        counter++;
                        qtysavesearch[position]=String.valueOf(counter);
                        checkedAddSub[position]=true;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checkedAddSub[position]=false;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            });
```

Please Help me Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code for getting the particular textview value?

Comment: holder.lserving_qty.getText().toString()

Comment: thank @AbhishekChaubey for specifying the above

Comment: @Leog holder.lserving_qty.getText().toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onShowButtonClickHandler(View v) {
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) rl.getChildAt(0);
        TextView textView = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
        if (!isTablet) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .show(mapFragment)
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_out)
                    .hide(vehiclesFragment)
                    .commit();
            isVehiclesOpen = false;
        }
        vehicleToShowHide = textView.getText().toString();
        mapFragment.hideVehicle(vehicleToShowHide);
    }
```

Get the parentlayout position and then try to get the position of that child with respect to that layout and then u will get that particular Row on which u click the butoon

Comment: how to get the childAt(position) ?

Comment: Thanks buddy it helped Me by changing some of the contextual and it heps me

Comment: i have made some of the edit so review please so that other user can get only that part which is useful thank u

Answer (score 0):

Your "holder" is a field of your adapter, so it will be reassigned each time the getView() method is called, thus its final value is the "last one", and this is the reason why you were getting the value of the last one.

How to solve your problem?

The key point is to find the convertview with the plus button, thus you can get the right holder from it.
Assume that your plus button is a direct Child View of the convertview, you can get the right ViewHolder in the onClick(View v) method with the following code:

```
// Get the View Parent of the plus button, and its parent surely is the convertview.
ViewParent vp = v.getParent();
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)((View)vp).getTag();
// Now you have the right holder and you can get the proper text with it.
```